# web api route to only match on first segment of URL

Tags: routes, asp.net-web-api

I want my ASP.NET Web API to take this request:

```
http://domain.com/proxy/service?id=12
```

and only matching on the first /proxy/ part, route it to this controller action. The action's parameter would therefore be the rest of the URL: "service?id=124"

```
public string Get(string url)
{
    //Calls external resource and returns response
}
```

The urls could have any number of segments, after the querystring (its acting as a proxy to call off to several remote servers), but it won't match.

I'd like something like this below, but it doesn't work. As soon as the url has more than one segment after the /proxy/ part it fairs to match it.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "ApiProxy",
      routeTemplate: "proxy/{resourcePath}",
      defaults: new { Controller = "Proxy", Action="Get" }
 );
```

I have looking into MessageHandlers, but they get fired for all requests, which doesn't seem ideal and was hoping I could just tie it into the standard Web Api routing instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `{resourcePath}`  to `{*resourcePath}`

**Update**

I missed the fact that you are trying to create a proxy.  You really want to use a message handler for that instead of a controller.  When you create a route, you can pass a message handler that is only applied when that route is matched.
By using a messagehandler it is easier to proxy the request asynchronously and it should be much faster than going through all the goop in ApiController.

Comment: That almost works, but it returns "service", rather than "service?id=12" as the parameter passed to the Action method. I ended up having to use the Request.Uri on the context to manually strip out the url...not very mvc ;)

Comment: Ah cool, I did noticed it slowed the query down quite a bit. I'll look at the MessageHandler. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using wildcards such as {*resourcePath} only seemed to fix part of the problem. It meant it would call the correct Action, but it would only pass through part of the URL as the resourcePath parameter into the Action method. It doesn't like Urls with querystrings.

I had to use the wildcard in combination with a the Request.Uri to manually strip out the rest of the URL.